# iPhone -> dynamic cell height

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a UITableView and a Cell which I design with Interface Builder.
I have two labels there.
The problem is, that one of the labels is text which can be 500 words or 10 words.

So I need a dynamic cell height. How can I handle this, because otherwise I have empty space or the cell height is not enough.

Perhaps someone has an idea how to do this?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To know the size of your text, you can use this method:

```
- (CGFloat)measureTextHeight:(NSString*)text fontName:(NSString*)fontName fontSize:(CGFloat)fontSize constrainedToSize:(CGSize)constrainedToSize {
CGSize mTempSize = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:fontSize] constrainedToSize:constrainedToSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
return mTempSize.height; }
```

Then you can set your size cell with:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableVIew*)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Comment: Hm, isn't it possible to read all values from the UILabel field? because if I change a size, I havealso to change it here, and what is the `constrainedToSize`?

Comment: constrainedToSize is the width of your screen (or your UILabel if it does not fit the screen width).

Comment: Ah, okay, it seems to work, but where and how can I resize the UILabel?

Comment: You just need to change your UILabel frame. With something like this : label.frame = CGRectMake(label.frame.origin.x, label.frame.origin.y, constrainedToSize.width, [self measureTextHeight:label.text fontName:fontName fontSize:fontSize constrainedToSize:constrainedToSize]);

Answer (score 2):

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableVIew*) tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath *) indexPath
{
   //here u can check the row number and ur labels and return ur custom height.
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's clear, but how can I check these heights of the labels? Because I define it in the IB with i.e. 40px, this is then a fix size. So if I ask for the Label height, I will get always 40px.

Comment: good question...i have no any nice ideas...only ugly one that u can count the chars and guess based on ur font what will be its height:S