# Detect linebreak in UITextView

Tags: objective-c, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

Is there a way to detect line breaks occurred by the user or when the textview automatically changes line. I am going to change the height of the textview depending on the number of lines.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the method proposed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2166919/756339) to find the occurrences of @"\n", the newline character.
You can see if the string change using the textViewDidChange: protocol method ([apple doc here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html)).

If you want the heigh, directly, look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4865401/756339). I think it can help.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the number of rows which is actually what i wanted to do.

numLines = textView.contentSize.height/textView.font.leading;

put this code into textViewDidChange: