# Get Rid of Line Breaks UITextView

Tags: ios, uitextview, line-breaks

For the past few hours I have been trying to get rid of all the visible line breaks that my UITextView is showing. So I thought it would be as simple as running this code:

```
NSString *trimmedString = [textView.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
[textView setText:trimmedString];
```

However, it seems like nothing changes after executing that. The textView text is in fact being set to trimmedString but the line breaks are still visible like shown in the picture below.

[image]

How would I properly fix this so I can have the text shown in the image (as an example), be without line breaks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it with this code:

```
NSString *trimmedString = [textView.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\r\n" withString:@" "];
[textView setText:trimmedString];
```

Comment: Curious. Was the text typed in normally into the text view or did it come from some other source?

Comment: @rmaddy It is an OCR app so it gets downloaded from a server and put into the UITextView.

Answer (score 0):

I just put your example code in the `viewDidLoad` of my `UIViewController` and totally saw the expected result. Here is one screenshot without your code snippet:
[image: Showing the default state]

And here is a screenshot with the code snippet:
[image: Showing modified state]

You can see that the line breaks were replaced. Did you connected your `UITextView Outlet` correctly ?

Comment: Yes everything is connected, both the delegate and IBOutlet to the textView so I am not sure why it isn't working as expected.

Comment: I actually ended up finding slightly different code that fixed it. I posted it as an answer.

Comment: Are you sure the line breaks in your text are properly formatted ? Are you sure the line breaks get detected ? Maybe you should try this and have a look if the line breaks get detected: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252404/detect-linebreak-in-uitextview

Comment: Ah I see it looks like my last guess was right. The line breaks are formatted as "windows line breaks" \r\n and not Unix like \n.